# Nullpointerexception: failed to set up android modules

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, nullpointerexception

When I try to import my Android Project I get three times the message "Nullpointerexception: null" and also the following error:
Nullpointerexception: failed to set up android modules
The error occurred after deleting by accident the .AndroidStudio1.4 folder, starting Android Studio, replacing the folder with the one in the recycle bin and starting Android Studio again.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please paste your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reinstall Android studio ?

Please do it and re-import your project, i think it's the simplest solution.

if it doesn't work, please paste your error log like @FireSun asked you.

Comment: Reinstalling Android Studio worked indeed.